Complexity Class of Language L: Formula in CNF and DTM Consistency with Variable Assignments
L = {⟨F, M⟩: F is a formula in CNF, M is a DTM,
and for every assignment A to the variables of F, M(A) = F[A]}.
is it in
P, NP ∩ co-NP, NP, co-NP, R, RE, co-RE, RE ∪ co-RE Complement
thanks

To show that $L \not\in \mathsf{coRE}$, here's a mapping reduction $A_\mathsf{TM} \leq_\mathrm{m} L$:
The mapping $f$ maps $\langle M, w\rangle$ to $\langle F, T\rangle$ where $F = \top$ (the empty AND formula) and $T$ = "Ignore its input and simulate $M$ on $w$."
Then note that $T$ accepts all variable assignments to $F$ iff $M$ accepts $w$.
To show that $L \not\in \mathsf{RE}$, here's a mapping reduction $\overline{A_\mathsf{TM}} \leq_\mathrm{m} L$:
The mapping $f$ maps $\langle M, w\rangle$ to $\langle F, T\rangle$ where $F = \perp$ (the empty OR formula) and $T$ = "Ignore its input and simulate $M$ on $w$."
Then note that $T$ rejects all variable assignments to $F$ (possibly by looping) iff $M$ rejects $w$ (possibly by looping).
